# does gensim Word2Vec include neighboring sentences in context?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am working to calculate similarities of labels of materials. Where each label might have 1-10 words in it. I am using gensim word2vec to find cosine similarities.

My approach is simply to treat each label as a 'sentence' and tokenize each word.
**example:**
**labels** = ['wooden desk cherry', 'long sleeve shirt cotton',..]

**sentences** = [['wooden', 'desk', 'cherry'], ['long', 'sleeve', 'shirt', 'cotton'],..]

My question is does word2vec take neighboring sentences into its context. for example if i am using a window = 2, when looking at words around 'long', will 'cherry' be included or only 'sleeve'.

If neighboring sentences are considered is there a way to only consider words within the target words sentence.

Thanks for any help. I have read the Word2Vec documentation and couldn't find any information about this.

Comment: only 'sleeve' i think. if you want cheery to be included why even bother splitting the sentences ?

Comment: those are two different sentences. I don't want 'cherry' included. Im trying to make sure that only words from within the target words sentence are included.

Answer (score 2):

Gensim's `Word2Vec` works on whatever chunks of text you provide to it. So, when you supply `['wooden', 'desk', 'cherry']` and `['long', 'sleeve', 'shirt', 'cotton']` as separate items in the training corpus, no training windows will blend them together.

(Separately: in sufficiently-large training sets, it'd be unlikely for such 'bleed-over' to make much difference, even if it did happen. It'd be a little bit of random-interference, since the source data doesn't truly imply those words appeared together. But the curve-balls it throws the training should be swamped out by the 'real signal' in true co-occurrences.)

Comment: So just to clarify, when you say 'separate items' are you referring to separate sentences? I believe the input for gensim Word2Vec is supposed to be a list of lists where the inner lists represent a sentence. If training windows do not cross into neighboring sentences than that is the answer i was looking for.

Comment: Training windows do not cross the list-of-tokens boundaries you've used. (The class doesn't stitch anything back together.) The choice of `sentences` for the parameter names has been unfortunately over-specific – it doesn't need to specifically be real sentences, & in fact many productive uses of `Word2Vec` even leave sentence-breaking punctuation in as pseudo-word tokens, when they provide longer texts as each item. (To the extent that in many kinds of source material, adjacent sentences are highly related, such larger chunks may even improve results.) But you're safe with your splits!

Comment: Great, Thanks for your help!